# Admob not updating Impressions/Clicks

Tags: android, admob

I've implemented Admob into my APP and it sounds to be working with my app , but the problem is since I added it I got about 20 downloads but on Admob website it shows 0 Impressions / 0 clicks . Is that normal that Admob takes some time to update statistics ? or It's a problem in my setup?

[click link and solve your problem?](https://www.bloggermafia.online/2019/09/Admob-Revenue.html)

Comment: It does take some time, I think they say so in their agreement or elsewhere. It can take up to 48 or I don' remember how many hours

Comment: Okey good to know . So I don't have to worry about the chance of having a wrong setup ?

Comment: @AlphaCode Right, Either you have to wait at least 24 hours.